# zsh: command not found: services

Tags: zsh, raspbian, oh-my-zsh

When i installed zsh and add oh-my-zsh i cant execute command like ifconfig and services.

To install zsh i execute this commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zsh
$ wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh
$ chsh -s `which zsh`
```

My .zshrc look like this:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
  export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
  export ZSH=/home/kuchar/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load. Optionally, if you set this to "random"
# it'll load a random theme each time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="af-magic"

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
# sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/rsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

When i execute `PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` nothing change, still cant use ifconfig and service.

Comment: What OS are you using? Were you able to use the "service" command with a different shell, like bash? If so, what's the output of `command -v service` in that shell?

Comment: `ifconfig` and `service` are likely in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`.

Comment: The operating system is hidden in the tags, jayhendren.  Nonetheless, this is a poorly written question.  It has: no demonstration of the command not working; no demonstration of the Z Shell in action, or that the changed shell was actually invoked at all; confusion as to the name of the command being sought, sometimes `service` mosttimes `services`; `which zsh`, but not `which ifconfig` or `which services`; no indication that an `ifconfig` command is even installed in the first place (as opposed to the tools from the iproute2 package).

Comment: @jayhendren now when i go back to bash i got `bash: ifconfig: command not found` also on `command -v service` nothing return. I use Raspbian. I was able to use `service` and `ifconfig` before i install oh-my-zsh

Comment: Why down vote on this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution for this problem**:

Change this in your zsh config file `~/.zshrc`
`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` 
to this:
`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH`
Save and reboot for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Open up your ~/.bashrc and ~/.zshrc files side by side, copy all command PATHs you are missing from your .bashrc into your .zshrc file, save, and restart your terminal. All set!